# Can IntelliJ plugins contribute Code Vision and gutter icons?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Those who use IntelliJ IDEA and other IDEs in that family will be familiar with the 'Code Vision' additions to the editor window, decorating above lines with the number of usages, most recent committeer, and so on.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Code Vision shows '2 usages' above a Java field]

They'll also be familiar with the actionable gutter icons, such as the 'Run' icon alongside JUnit or Spock test methods.

[image: A run icon in the gutter of IntelliJ IDEA alongside a Spock test]

Are these capabilities available to plugin developers to contribute their own developments?

Comment: See https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/inlay-hints.html. If you have further questions, refer to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html for the best way to ask.

Comment: Thanks. That's half the answer - I don't see an answer for gutter icons.

Comment: See https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/line-marker-provider.html#best-practices-for-implementing-line-marker-providers regarding the gutter icons.